# How do I implement clipboard.js?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

How to create a "Copy" button to copy a text in Drupal 8?

I downloaded the following library in the folder `/libraries` :

https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js

Here is my `bootstrap_subtheme_front_office.info.ym`l file :

```
name: Bootstrap Subtheme Front Office
type: theme
description: 'SASS starter kit for a Bootstrap Barrio SubTheme.'
# version: VERSION
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
base theme: bootstrap_barrio

libraries:
  - bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/bootstrap
  - bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/global-styling
  - bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/clipboardjs
libraries-override:
  bootstrap_barrio/global-styling: true
  bootstrap_barrio/file: true
regions:
  navigation_collapsible_first: 'Navigation (Collapsible first)'
  navigation_collapsible_left: 'Navigation (Collapsible left)'
  navigation: 'Navigation'
  navigation_collapsible_right: 'Navigation (Collapsible right)'
  navigation_collapsible_second: 'Navigation (Collapsible second)'
  breadcrumb: 'Breadcrumb'
  header: 'Top Bar'
  sidebar_first: 'Primary'
  highlighted: 'Highlighted'
  help: 'Help'
  content: 'Content'
  sidebar_second: 'Secondary'
  footer: 'Footer'

# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2020-10-11
version: '5.0.2'
project: 'bootstrap_subtheme_front_office'
datestamp: 1602444143
```

I declared the library in this file `bootstrap_subtheme_front_office.libraries.yml` :

```
bootstrap:
  js:
    /libraries/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      /libraries/bootswatch/dist/flatly/bootstrap.min.css: {}
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  js: 
    js/popper.min.js: {}
    js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
    js/barrio.js: {}
    js/custom.js: {}
    js/back-to-top.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/style.min.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
clipboardjs:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    /libraries/clipboard.js/dist/clipboard.min.js: {}
```

I created this HTML code :

```
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn't mean you should — clipboard.js">
  Copy to clipboard
</button>
```

I have checked the source code of my pages and the library is loaded :

[image]

When I click on the button, it does not "Copy". How to make this library work with Drupal 8 ?

https://clipboardjs.com/

There is a step and I don't know what to do in Drupal :

> Now, you need to instantiate it by passing a DOM selector, HTML
> element, or list of HTML elements.
>
> `new ClipboardJS('.btn');`

Comment: What's wrong with https://www.drupal.org/project/clipboardjs?

Comment: If there's a contrib module, providing a stable release, covered for security advisory coverage, managing all the dependencies, why do you want to reinvent the wheel? You could just go there and look how it's done and you have the answer to your question. "Minimally maintained" doesn't say a lot, except that after that relatively simple module was finished there is no need to implement any more magic, because why? It's just done.

Comment: Then open an issue in the module's issue queue "This module is a mess". Let's see where this leads to. Nowhere. clipboard.js has [pretty clear instructions](https://clipboardjs.co) what markup and scripts it expects to work. It seems you added the library to every page already. Can you verify it gets loaded? Fine. Then continue  with the instructions from clibboard.js and add either an `data-clipboard-text` or `data-clipboard-target` attribute. I don't see that in your code. Alternatively go for custom JS. They have samples on that as well.

Comment: On the page it says `Now, you need to instantiate it ...` <-- You need to fire it somehow. Maybe in your custom.js that's also in the libs. It would probably be better to make `clipboardjs` its own library definition in the *.libraries.yml and then add `- bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/clipboardjs` to the `dependencies:` array of `global-styling`. Maybe it also works if you switch the order and move custom.js to the end. The module would have taught you about the instantiation: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/clipboardjs/-/blob/2.0.x/js/clipboard.js#L15. "Dead". Sure. 

Comment: @leymannx You mean, do it like that ? https://pastebin.com/76LdX3WK and https://pastebin.com/8216ZdxN

Comment: I don't think I'll ever understand this comments-under-a-question approach to debugging - why ask leymannx if that's what he meant? Why not just try it yourself and see?

Comment: I tested and it does not work. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following:

1. Install the [Clipboard.js](https://www.drupal.org/project/clipboardjs) Drupal module and enable it.
2. If you installed it with Composer, you can skip this step. If not, have the clipboard.js file located at `/libraries/clipboard.js/dist/clipboard.js`. Because that's where the module expects it: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/clipboardjs/-/blob/2.0.0/clipboardjs.libraries.yml#L27
3. Now attach the library either in `hook_preprocess_page` to every page or via `{{ attach_library('clipboardjs/clipboardjs') }}` directly in Twig.
4. Now have either an `<a>`, an `<input>` or a `<button>` with `class="clipboardjs-button"`. Because that's how the module initiates the library: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/clipboardjs/-/blob/2.0.0/js/clipboard.js#L15.

And you are done. And you can follow up adding the [Clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/)-specific attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the library is loaded on the page with your TWIG code, but the "Copy" does not work. Here is my HTML code `<button class="clipboardjs-button">
  Copy to clipboard
</button>`

Comment: @yoyo – Of course it doesn't work. Where are you telling the button what to do? Which element to target? Which text to copy? Which action to perform, cut or copy? There are clipboard.js-specific data attributes you have to add which I already told you three times.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/D87C6Bnx I tested this code, it doesn't work. There is no explanation for this module, absolutely nothing. No example. The documentation is a mess and shows the beginning of an instruction for Drupal 7 in the Drupal 8 version. We don't even know how it works.

Comment: @yoyo – Neither is true. You are missing `class="clipboardjs-button"`. We are going in circles.

Comment: I redid my code and it makes no difference. What is missing `<input id="foo" value="my text">
<button class="btn btn clipboardjs-button" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#foo">
    copy
</button>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested in a solution, I have found the following pages that help in https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js :

Under the demo sub-directory:
https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/blob/master/demo/

You can find for instance "function-text.html" and "target-textarea.html" among others...

So, I have copied the content from those files and paste them in my page, from there I started modifying to what I have and what I need, for instance, from file "constructor-node.html" I have copied:

(Text between * is what I have modified, eg.: *Click to copy*...)

```
   <!-- 1. Define some markup -->
    <div id="btn" data-clipboard-text="*The text I want to be copied*">
      <span>*Click to copy*</span>
    </div>

    <!-- 2. Include library -->
    <script src="*https://myserver.com/mydrupal/libraries*/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

    <!-- 3. Instantiate clipboard by passing a HTML element -->
    <script>
      var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
      var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(btn);

      clipboard.on('success', function (e) {
        console.info('Action:', e.action);
        console.info('Text:', e.text);
        console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);
      });

      clipboard.on('error', function (e) {
        console.info('Action:', e.action);
        console.info('Text:', e.text);
        console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);
      });
    </script>
```

This way it worked for me.

Good luck!!

By the way, the DOM Selector is the function that selects the element that triggers the action, I have just learned from here: https://blog.bitsrc.io/dom-selectors-explained-70260049aaf0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think I did a good improvement, isn't it?